# assigning event listeners to multiple movie clips (ie., alphabets) to play different mp3 files (ie.,pronounciation) in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am trying to develop a simple drag & drop alphabet learning app in flash cs6 with as3 in which the player is supposed to drag each alphabet and position it in the right order...and when the player clicks on a particular alphabet (movie clip) the respective pronunciation (mp3 audio) is supposed to be played...i can assign the audio clip to only a single alphabet movie clip..but when i try to achieve the same for every other alphabet i fail to do so..my code runs as follows....can someone please tell me how to assign each alphabet a different audio file so that when the player clicks on that alphabet "movie clip" the pronunciation audio clip for that alphabet is played....

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var alphabets:Array = new Array(a1, a2, a3, a4);

var sound1:Letter1 = new Letter1();
a1:addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play1);
function play1(e:MouseEvent):void
{  sound1.play(); }

alphabets:addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMe);

function dragMe(e:MouseEvent):void
{  e.target.startDrag(); }

alphabets:addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe);

function dropMe(e:MouseEvent):void
{  e.target.stopDrag(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a simple class *SpeakingLetter* that extends MovieClip (or Sprite) and add a sound property to it. After that you assign different sound to different MovieClips, and add your MouseEvent.CLICK event listener to every SpeakingLetter object you have. It will be something like this:

```
// SpeakingLetter class
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SpeakingLetter extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var _sound:MySound;

        public function SpeakingLetter(inputSound:MySound) 
        {
            super();
            _sound = inputSound;
        }

        public function playSound():void
        {
            _sound.play();
        }   
    }
}
```

And your main code will be something like this

```
//MAIN CODE
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

//You should replace these values with your own - I don't know how you store your sounds
const speakingLetterSounds:Array = [new MySound("sound1"), new MySound("sound2"), new MySound("sound3")];

var speakingLetters:Array = [];
var numOfLetters:uint = 3;
for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfLetters; i++)
{
    var currentLeter:SpeakingLetter = new SpeakingLetter(speakingLetterSounds[i]);
    currentLeter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playLetterSound);
    speakingLetters.push(currentLeter);
}

function playLetterSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var currentLetter:SpeakingLetter = e.target as SpeakingLetter;
    currentLetter.playSound();
}
```

So you should just play the sound of the pressed letter, so it won't get messed.

Comment: since i am a newbie to as3 and i haven't yet ventured into pure OOP as yet...for the time being i got thru the problem by giving event listeners to each alphabet movie clip in its own timeline...this way it works perfectly well and solves my problem, though i would like to take some time and understand the solution (code) suggested by KumoKairo...